Does an index on columns not used in a SELECT query make a difference?
I have a table:
T(A, B, C, D)

With this query:
SELECT A
FROM T 
WHERE B = C

Does having an index on D make a difference in the performance of the given query?
Does having an index on columns that are not used in a select query make a difference?


Does having an index on D make a difference in the performance of the given query?
Does having an index on columns that are not used in a select query make a difference?

No to both questions.
An index on D is dead freight and not involved in the given query. It neither helps nor hinders it. There are hypothetical side effects of maintaining another index, by way of wasting resources. But, basically, it's a clear "No".
Actually useful index
In fact, the only (potentially) useful index for this query is a partial index of the form:
CREATE INDEX useful_idx ON t (a) WHERE b = c;

Proof:
fiddle
Creating such a tailored index only makes sense, if ...

... WHERE b = c is selective (only a small part of the table qualifies)
... that exact condition is used often enough to warrant the cost for maintaining another index.

The condition WHERE b = c cannot make use of a plain index on the involved columns. That's not how indexes work. You need a constant input value to look something up in the index. B = C has no such constant, both values change from row to row.


does having an index on D make a difference in the performance of the given query?

Probably not, but it could make the query slower, if RAM that might have been used for serving the query is instead be used towards the index.
Additionally, if your model of indexing is separate indices for columns A, B, and C, that's not how it works. For example, an index on column A alone is worthless for this query, and if you have separate indexes on columns B and C individually only one of them might possibly be used, and probably neither is helpful.
Instead, this query is best served by a single index for columns (B, C, include A) all in the same index and in that specific order (though you may be able to reverse C and B, since the B=C expression is equivalent to C=B).
The include means it doesn't have to worry about sorting/order for column A, and instead just uses the indexed A values so the database can fully serve the query from the index alone, without needing to go back to the original table.

The index you suggest cannot help. I added an answer.

Yes it does. The index will be larger because of the extra column so it does consume more IO and more RAM. If you can measure the difference, that's a different thing. You can measure this yourself.
Do you have queries that search for the D column?
